# Unable to access web server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, discord.js

I am following [this tutorial/guide](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/guidebot/tree/dashboard). Locally, it works, using `localhost` as the domain, and `8080` as the port.

Here's the local configuration:

```
"dashboard" : {
    "oauthSecret": `${process.env.oauthSecret}`,
    "callbackURL": `http://localhost:8080/callback`,
    "sessionSecret": "fakesessionsecret",
    "domain": "localhost",
    "port": 8080
  },
```

But now, I would like to use the app on Heroku, and access the web dashboard through `https://project-name.herokuapp.com`or through a custom domain, which I linked already to the DNS provided, in format `dashboard.example.com`.

`localhost` and/or the port does not work for Heroku, so I'm not sure what to change it to for it to work. I have already tried to change the domain to `xxx.herokudns.com`, port to `process.env.PORT`, domain to the custom one I set in Heroku - but they all result in the app crashing with status `503` when I visit the URL.

From what I see, the configuration domains and ports are used in these codes:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const passport = require("passport");

passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: client.appInfo.id,
    clientSecret: config.dashboard.oauthSecret, //from configuration
    callbackURL: config.dashboard.callbackURL, //from configuration
    scope: ["identify", "guilds"]
  }
...
app.locals.domain = config.dashboard.domain;
...
app.listen(client.config.dashboard.port);
```

So how do I access the web application from Heroku?

Comment: When you get a 503, are you checking your Heroku logs? Domain should be `"dashboard.example.com"` and port should be `process.env.PORT`. Better still, use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and a `.env` file to define your environment variables locally, and use Heroku's "Settings" tab to set the environment variables in production (in this instance, just `domain` – `port` is already set for you on each app launch).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and this actually worked. If you would mind, please answer the question so I can mark it as solved!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a 503, are you checking your Heroku logs? They should provide specific info about what's causing the crash.

The domain should be `dashboard.example.com` and the port should be `process.env.PORT`. Better still, use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and a .env file to define your environment variables locally, and use Heroku's "Settings" tab to set the environment variables in production (in this instance, just `domain` – `port` is already set for you on each app launch).